Android: Find list of apps for which the Accessibility Service is enabled
How can I find or get the list of applications that have the Accessibility service turned on? I know where to look to find this information for my own application. However, I would like to know the names of any additional apps that my device may have with the Accessibility service activated. How can I obtain this data?
I gone through the AccessibilityManager API as well as the AccessibilityService API, but couldn't find the needed information.
